# Invoking WCF IServiceBehavior and IOperationBehavior without calling a method

Tags: c#, wcf, iservicebehaviors

I'd like to be able to add a couple of behaviors without having to call a method forcing them to be to used.  A typical example is via an [InvokeErrorSupport] attribute whose purpose would be to fire off a test e-mail when deploying a service to ensure the error e-mails are coming through okay.  Thus saving magic strings in a request Parameter Object, one or more non-business logic related [OperationContract] methods etc dirtying up the contract (with single responsibility in mind).  We are more than happy to potentially invoke a method in other case such as our [Heartbeat] behavior and similar.

I have no problem writing the behaviors. It's a great feature of WCF but right now its looking like I'm going to have to add some method to the contract which I call such as Initialize which I'd lock down after start-up. Since, in this instance and more, the services are often external facing so we wish to avoid DoS attacks etc.

I've poked about client-side and can't see anyway and to be honest it kinda makes a degree of sense this functionality doesn't exist.

Can anybody offer any advice?

Comment: May be ServiceHostFactory could be helpful to inject the Email sending code when the service host instance being created.